# Redirecting stdout to a file in C through code

Tags: c, file

I am outputting to stdout. How can I redirect that to a new file through code? While we run the program we can redirect like `./sample > test.txt`. How can I do this when executing the sample program itself ? (C programming)

Answer (score 8):

You probably want to use [freopen](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/freopen.html).

Example from reference:

```
#include <stdio.h>
...
FILE *fp;
...
fp = freopen ("/tmp/logfile", "a+", stdout);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`freopen()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/freopen.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use `dup2()` system call and redirect the output to a file.