# Difference between perror() and printf()

Tags: c, linux, stdout, stderr

I had read that both `perror()` and `printf()` write to the terminal screen. But `perror()` writes to `stderr` while `printf()` writes to `stdout`. So, to print errors why is `perror()` used when `printf()` can do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385201/confused-about-stdin-stdout-and-stderr

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`printf()` cannot write to `stderr`.   `fprintf()` can.   `perror()` always does.

There is no requirement that writing to either `stdout` or `stderr` writes to a terminal screen - that is up to the implementation (since not all systems even have a terminal).   There is also no requirement that writing to `stdout` and `stderr` results in writing to the same device (e.g. one can be redirected to a file, while the other is redirected to a pipe).

`perror()` will be implemented with built-in knowledge of the meanings of error codes, represented by the static `errno`, which is used by various functions in the standard library to report error conditions.    The meanings of particular values are implementation defined (i.e. they vary between compilers and libraries).

Answer (score 2):

Because there could be configurations where you want `stderr` printed to the console but the other output not printed at all (for example, to remove verbosity). In other cases you may need to redirect `stderr` to write to a file, this is useful when you are in production and that file can be used to understand what went wrong on a remote computer you can't debug yourself.

In general, you gain more control on how console outputs are treated depending on their type.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2648339/2304450) to understand how you can do stream redirection in code.

Or, see [this link](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) on how you can force stream redirection to file or ignore a stream on an already compiled program (while invoking it in *bash*)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to other answers, you might use [fprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fprintf.3.html) on `stderr`  and [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) with [strerror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) like

```
 fprintf(stderr, "something wrong: %s\n", strerror(errno));
```

On GNU libc systems (many Linux systems), you could use instead `%m` conversion specifier instead:

```
fprintf(stderr, "something wrong: %m\n");
```

You conventionally should output error messages to `stderr` (see [stderr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stderr.3.html)); see also [syslog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) to use system logging.

Don't forget to end the format string with `\n`  since `stderr`  is often line buffered (but sometimes not) or else use [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html)

For example, you might want to show both the error, the filename and the current directory on `fopen` failure:

```
char* filename = somefilepath();
assert (filename != NULL);
FILE* f = fopen(filename, "r");
if (!f) {
   int e = errno; // keep errno, it could be later overwritten
   if (filename[0] == '/') /// absolute path
      fprintf(stderr, "failed to open %s : %s\n", filename, strerror(e));
   else { // we also try to show the current directory since relative path
      char dirbuf[128];
      memset (dirbuf, 0, sizeof(dirbuf));
      if (getcwd(dirbuf, sizeof(dirbuf)-1)) 
         fprintf(stderr, "failed to open %s in %s : %s\n", 
                 filename, dirbuf, sterror(e));
      else // unlikely case when getcwd failed so errno overwritten
         fprintf(stderr, "failed to open %s here : %s\n", 
                 filename, sterror(e));
   };
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE); // in all cases when fopen failed
 }
```

Remember that `errno`  could be overwritten by many failures (so we store it in `e`, in the unlikely case that `getcwd`  fails and overwrite `errno`).

If your program is a deamon (e.g. has called [daemon(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html)) you'll better use system log (i.e. call [openlog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/openlog.3.html) *after* calling `daemon`) since `daemon`  can redirect *stderr* to `/dev/null`

Answer (score 1):

There are three standard stream `stdin` `stdout` `stderr`. You can [refer](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Standard-Streams.html#Standard-Streams) to know what is important of different stream.

For error messages and diagnostics ,stderr is used , to print on stderr 
**Perror** is used. printf can not do that. Perror is also used to handle errors from system call

```
fd = open (pathname, flags, mode);
if (fd == -1) {
perror("open");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

You can refer more about this in book [The linux programming interface](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=2SAQAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=purpose+of+perror&source=bl&ots=qQt687DBvA&sig=eY-J7tLAjWSypbiwmn3JGMxftKs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjfycv1rsTJAhXF5YMKHc1YAZEQ6AEIUjAJ#v=onepage&q=purpose%20of%20perror&f=false)

`void perror(const char *s)`

Perror prints message in following sequence :

argument of `s` , a colon , a space , a short message concerning error whose error code currently in `errno`and newline

In standard C if `s` is null pointer than only message will be printed . other things will be ignored

To understand more you can also refer page 332 of [The complete reference C](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3OzFFMgEP0tU3RVcmh2Wm5ZUWs/edit)

Answer (score 1):

A big advantage of using perror():

It is sometimes very useful to redirect **stdout** into */dev/null* to only have access to errors since the verbosity of stdout might hide the errors that we need to fix.

Answer (score -3):

## perror

The general purpose of the function is to halt the execution process due to an error. The error message produced by perror is platform-depend. You can also print your own error message also.

## printf

The general purpose of the function is to print message user defined and continue the execution.

Comment: "*The general purpose of the function is to halt the execution process due to an error.*". `perror()` does *not* halt the program at all.

Comment: Err, so what please is the intention of your wording then?

Comment: @alk it is generally used to halt the process e.g. perror(errno);exit(1);

Comment: Well, then perror isn't used to halt the process. In your example, it's used together with halting the process. Thoug, I'm not sure I'd say that it's generally used only in that case. So please, don't mix perror with halting processes.